# Why does the global var debug get evaluated to [object Object]

Tags: javascript, ios, object, cordova, evaluation

Why does the global var debug get evaluated to [object Object] instead of to 1?  Consider this code:

```
var debug = 1;
function hum(mess) {
    alert('hum alert debug == ' + debug);
    console.log('hum console.log debug == ' + debug);
    if (debug == 1) {
        console.error('hum mess == ' + mess);
    } else {
        console.error('hum debug != 1 mess == ' + mess);
    }
}
```

When my code first runs the eval is made properly so my alert says 'debug==1' but later (perhaps after phonegap finishes loading) it starts giving me debug==[object Object].  I am developing using phonegap for ios using xcode and iphone simulator.

thanks

Comment: Because of the way string conversion works. Basically js types are a miss. Also alert is silly, stop using it.

Comment: May be a conflict between your code and the library you're using?  They could also be using a variable called debug but setting it to an object.

Comment: It looks like `debug` is being replaced by some other code. Use `DEBUG` and see if the same thing still happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've declared `debug` as a global variable and it's probably getting reassigned by other code loaded/executed later.  Try changing the variable name or making it not global.

Comment: Yup thats it, debug is geting reassigned somewhere in phonegap i guess.  Thought of that but it seemed wishful thinking that is would be so simple.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

somewhere later in your code the platform ur working on changes the value of debug to an object.
change the variable name from debug to smthing nt that obvious like new_debug

Answer (score 0):

Your debug variable gets replaced by phonegap which creates a debug object see:

http://www.daveoncode.com/2010/01/12/debugging-phonegap-applications-using-xcode-console/

Snippet from there:
Fortunately PhoneGap offers a way to access to Xcode console and print messages by choosing among three different levels: log, warn and error. In order to print a message, we have to use the **debug object, which has scope window (it is a global object)**, in this way: